# Flutter method was called on null

Tags: http, dart, flutter, bloc

I am learning flutter and I am trying to implement login screens. I am following this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-login-tutorial-with-flutter-bloc-ea606ef701ad) and I am adding Dio for API calls. Problem is when I click the Login button I am getting error "NoSuchMethod: the method 'authenticate' was called on null".

Here is what I have done.

UserRepository.dart

```
    Future<String> authenticate({
    @required String username,
    @required String password,
  }) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    Map<String, String> body = {
      'username': username,
      'password': password,
      'rememberMe': "false"
    };

    LoginResponse response = await apiRepository.authenticate(body);
    print(response.toString());

    return 'token';
  }
```

And for the ApiProvider.dart I have this.

```
class ApiRepository {
  final String _baseUrl = "http://myserver/api";
  Dio _dio;

  ApiProvider() {
    BaseOptions options = new BaseOptions(
        baseUrl: _baseUrl, receiveTimeout: 5000, connectTimeout: 5000);
    _dio = new Dio(options);
  }

  Future<LoginResponse> authenticate(Map<String, String> body) async {
    try {
      Response response =
          await _dio.post(_baseUrl + "/authenticate", data: body);
      print(response.data);
      return LoginResponse.fromJson(response.data);
    } catch (error, stacktrace) {
      print("Exception occured: $error stackTrace: $stacktrace");
      return LoginResponse.withError(_handleError(error));
    }
  }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible to duplicate question of: [Flutter - The method was called on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52046870/flutter-the-method-was-called-on-null)

Comment: Where have you created the `apiRepository` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, thanks to @Spectarion. My mistake was in instantiation of apiRepository.

The correct way is `ApiRepository apiRepository = new ApiRepository();`

Mine was `ApiRepository apiRepository;`