# The method was called on null Flutter error

Tags: flutter

I have seen many people having this error in other StackOverflow posts but when I am struggling to implement the answers to other questions to my own code. The code being used is from the GitHub repository https://github.com/sbis04/events_demo.
This is how I call the method:

```
class _ThirdRoute extends State<ThirdRoute> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Calendar"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          DashboardScreen(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the method in another .dart file:

```
class DashboardScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashboardScreenState createState() => _DashboardScreenState();
}

class _DashboardScreenState extends State<DashboardScreen> {
  Storage storage = Storage();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.grey, //change your color here
        ),
        title: Text(
          'Event Details',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 22,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => CreateScreen(),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 16.0,
          right: 16.0,
        ),
        child: Container(
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: storage.retrieveEvents(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                if (snapshot.data.documents.length > 0) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      Map<String, dynamic> eventInfo = snapshot.data.documents[index].data();

                      EventInfo event = EventInfo.fromMap(eventInfo);

                      DateTime startTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(event.startTimeInEpoch);
                      DateTime endTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(event.endTimeInEpoch);

                      String startTimeString = DateFormat.jm().format(startTime);
                      String endTimeString = DateFormat.jm().format(endTime);
                      String dateString = DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(startTime);

                      return Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).push(
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => EditScreen(event: event),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  bottom: 16.0,
                                  top: 16.0,
                                  left: 16.0,
                                  right: 16.0,
                                ),
=                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                                    Text(
                                      event.description,
                                      maxLines: 2,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        event.link,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                                    Row(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        Container(
                                          height: 50,
                                          width: 5,
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                                        Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              dateString,
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              '$startTimeString - $endTimeString',
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'No Events',
                    ),
                  );
                }
              }
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  strokeWidth: 2,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If anyone would be able to give me some advice on how to solve the error:

> The method 'collection' was called on null. Receiver: null. Tried calling: collection("events"). The relevant error-causing widget was DashboardScreen

*EDIT* This is my storage.dart file as requested in the comments:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'calendar_client.dart';

final CollectionReference mainCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('event');
final DocumentReference documentReference = mainCollection.doc('test');

class Storage {
  Future<void> storeEventData(EventInfo eventInfo) async {
    DocumentReference documentReferencer = documentReference.collection('events').doc(eventInfo.id);

    Map<String, dynamic> data = eventInfo.toJson();

    print('DATA:\n$data');

    await documentReferencer.set(data).whenComplete(() {
      print("Event added to the database, id: {${eventInfo.id}}");
    }).catchError((e) => print(e));
  }

  Future<void> updateEventData(EventInfo eventInfo) async {
    DocumentReference documentReferencer = documentReference.collection('events').doc(eventInfo.id);

    Map<String, dynamic> data = eventInfo.toJson();

    print('DATA:\n$data');

    await documentReferencer.update(data).whenComplete(() {
      print("Event updated in the database, id: {${eventInfo.id}}");
    }).catchError((e) => print(e));
  }

  Future<void> deleteEvent({@required String id}) async {
    DocumentReference documentReferencer = documentReference.collection('events').doc(id);

    await documentReferencer.delete().catchError((e) => print(e));

    print('Event deleted, id: $id');
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> retrieveEvents() {
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> myClasses = documentReference.collection('events').orderBy('start').snapshots();

    return myClasses;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete.

Comment: Please post the full code of DashboardScreen

Comment: Sorry it was just long so I didn't know whether to add the full thing or not - I have added it now!

Comment: There is no need to have a long code. Please remove all the unnecessary code like styles or widget that does not depend on any variable.

You can also bound the portion of code that generates the error commenting your code and uncommenting little fragments. Next, whether a fragment doesn't generate error remove it.

Comment: I'm willing to bet the issues is caused within your `Storage` class, which you unfortunately didn't include in the question. Also, can you post the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - The method was called on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52046870/flutter-the-method-was-called-on-null)

Comment: @FrankMoreno I know but someone had requested the full code but I have removed most of the styles. Thank you for your advice on error checking!

Comment: @Riwen I have included the storage class as requested and that is the only error I receive. Im not too sure how to get the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: @Jiya It answers it to some extent as I know that I may need to initialise it but because I am using the Google Calendar API code, I am not too sure how to do this.

Comment: @ajnabz your complete code is not needed, but a complete code that can be executed does.

To reproduce your error, you should share the less code as possible but completed in itself to reproduce it without garbage around.