# Flutter listen to one document change using provider

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I have seen examples of listening to document changes in `streambuilder`, but is it possible to use it in providers? I want to listen to changes in the document in `userinfo` collection.

[image: my firebase config]

Here is my code:

in `databaseservice.dart`

```
      Stream <DocumentSnapshot> get info{
        return userinfo.doc(uid).snapshots();
      }
```

In main

```
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<DocumentSnapshot>.value(
          value: DatabaseService().info
        ), // other providers
```

In wrapper where I need to see the change:

```
    final info = Provider.of<DocumentSnapshot>(context).data();
```

However, I'll first get error:

```
    The method 'data' was called on null.
    Receiver: null
    Tried calling: data()
```

And later, the info variable is giving me null instead of a map.

I want to let users input their name and age after their first signup, but not when they sign in. So my idea is that when users sign up, there will be a new document in the collection, "userinfo", which sets their age and name as `null` at first.

Then the wrapper checks if the name is `null`. If `null`, it will turn to the gather information page. If it has a value, it will turn to the home page.

Could anyone tell me where I am doing wrong with my document snapshot thing, or have a better idea to implement this?

Comment: As per your error message you need to initialise the .data() correctly. If you have a look at this SO thread for [more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52046870/flutter-the-method-was-called-on-null)