# Getting Error in flutter:-The getter was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I am trying to get the maxDistance selected by the user and keep on getting this error. This is the complete code from where I am getting my data to where I am displaying. And in Cloud Firestore also the data is saved but I don't know why I am not able to display that data here. Pls help me out. Thanks.And I am getting this Error:-

```
 The getter 'maxDistance' was called on null.
 Receiver: null
 Tried calling: maxDistance
```

This is the screen where I am calling it:-

```
   class More extends StatefulWidget{
  final CreateAccountData currentUser;
  More({this.currentUser,}) ;

   @override
 _MoreState createState() => new _MoreState();
}

class _MoreState extends State<More>
 with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
Map<String, dynamic> changeValues = {};

 final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 int distance;
 String currentuser;
 int freeR;
  int paidR;

  @override
 void initState() {
super.initState();
freeR =  500;
paidR =  500;
setState(() {
  if (widget.currentUser.maxDistance > freeR) {
    widget.currentUser.maxDistance = freeR.round();
    changeValues.addAll({'maximum_distance': freeR.round()});
  } else if (
      widget.currentUser.maxDistance >= paidR) {
    widget.currentUser.maxDistance = paidR.round();
    changeValues.addAll({'maximum_distance': paidR.round()});
  }
    distance = widget.currentUser.maxDistance.round();
    });

  }
  @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  if (changeValues.length > 0) {
  updateData();
  }
}

 Future updateData() async {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("users")
    .doc(widget.currentUser.uid)
    .set(changeValues,SetOptions( merge: true));

 }
```

This is where I am displaying:-

```
     Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
               child: Card(
               child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                 child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                  "Maximum distance",
                   style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                                color: mRed,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                          ),
                          trailing: Text(
                            "$distance Km.",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          subtitle: Slider(
                               value: distance.toDouble(),
                              inactiveColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                              min: 1.0,
                              max: 500,
                              activeColor: mRed,
                              onChanged: (val) {
                                changeValues
                                    .addAll({'maximum_distance': val.round()});
                                setState(() {
                                  distance = val.round();
                                });
                              }),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

This is MODEL class from where I am getting my data:-

```
      class CreateAccountData {

  final String name, email,DOB,age,uid,username, countryCode ,
           address,phone, password,profilepic,showGender,gender;
 final Map coordinates,editInfo,ageRange;
 final List hobbies ;
int maxDistance;
 var distanceBW;

  CreateAccountData({this.name,this.email,this.DOB,this.age,
this.username,this.uid,this.countryCode,this.address,
this.phone, this.password,this.profilepic,this.coordinates,
this.hobbies,this.gender,this.showGender,this.ageRange,this.maxDistance,
this.editInfo,this.distanceBW});


     factory CreateAccountData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)    {
  return CreateAccountData(
    name: json['name'],
    email: json['email'],
    age:json['age'],
    DOB:json['DOB'],
    gender: json['gender'],
    hobbies: json['hobbies']['list'],
    address: json['location']['address'],
    coordinates: json['location'],
    username:json['username'],
    uid:json['uid'],
     editInfo:json['editInfo'],
    maxDistance:json['maximum_distance'],
    showGender:json['showGender'],
     phone: json['phone'],
    profilepic : json['profilepic']
);
  }

 factory CreateAccountData.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc){
 return CreateAccountData(
    uid: doc['uid'],
    phone: doc['phone'],
    name: doc['name'],
    editInfo: doc['editInfo'],
    ageRange: doc['age_range'],
    showGender: doc['showGender'],
    maxDistance: doc['maximum_distance'],
    age:doc['age'],
    address: doc['location']['address'],
    coordinates: doc['location'],
  
);
}

 Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
  return {
  'name':name,
  'email': email,
  'age': age,
  'username':username,
  'DOB':DOB,
  'gender':gender,
  'uid':uid,
  'showGender':showGender,
  'address':address,
  'editInfo':editInfo,
  'hobbies':hobbies,
  'location':coordinates,
  'maximum_distance':maxDistance,
  'phone' : phone,
  'profilepic':profilepic,
};
 }

 }
```

The bottomNav screen from where user switches to other tabs:-

```
       class BottomNav extends StatefulWidget {
       @override
     _BottomNavState createState() => _BottomNavState();
  }

  class _BottomNavState  extends State<BottomNav> {
   int _index = 0;
    List<Widget> _items = [
   Home(),
  UserProfile(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,imageList:    [],currentIndex:0),
  Notifications(),
  Chat(),
  More(),
  ];
```

Tried passing currentUser in More():-
Then it gives me this:-

```
    The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'CreateAccountData.
     Undefined name 'currentUser'.
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the screen that navigates to `More`? You need to pass the `currentUser` to `More`.

Comment: updated, pls check, may be I am passing it wrong, pls guide me.

Answer (score 0):

please check this line with debug points

```
if (widget.currentUser.maxDistance > freeR) {
```

I think currentUser is null in here if yes this might fix your problem

change the second line in this to

```
  class More extends StatefulWidget{
      final CreateAccountData currentUser;
      More({this.currentUser,}) ;
```

to this

```
CreateAccountData currentUser = CreateAccountData();
```

if it didn't fix your problem make sure you are sending currentUser to this widget

Comment: Yes, I think currentUser is not coming to this widget. How can I do that? Where and what changes I need to make?

Comment: have you checked it as I said? because 
final CreateAccountData currentUser; 
the line can make lots of problems... but if you want to make sure go back to the widget you are calling More  Widget... see if you are sending anything at all? if yes check it with debug points to make sure it is not empty or null

Comment: If I change the name "CreateAccountData" into  "User", then I get another error that :- The getter 'maxDistance' isn't defined for the type 'User'.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this:- CreateAccountData currentUser = CreateAccountData(); it didn't work.

Comment: ok so check if you are sending anything to this widget or not

Comment: if u got 2 mins can I share my screen with u on any desk? if its ok with u.

Comment: I am stuck in this from two days, don't know what I am missing

Comment: I would like to but I am at work right now I might be able to help you in 5 hours from now

Answer (score 0):

debug currentUser. I think you didn't pass currentUser to this page.

`widget?.currentUser?.maxDistance != null`

**check like this**

```
setState(() {
if(widget?.currentUser?.maxDistance != null){
  if (widget.currentUser.maxDistance > freeR) {
    widget.currentUser.maxDistance = freeR.round();
    changeValues.addAll({'maximum_distance': freeR.round()});
  } else if (
      widget.currentUser.maxDistance >= paidR) {
    widget.currentUser.maxDistance = paidR.round();
    changeValues.addAll({'maximum_distance': paidR.round()});
  }
    distance = widget.currentUser.maxDistance.round();
 } else {
    print('currentUser is null ${widget?.currentUser?.maxDistance}')
 }
});
```

Comment: yes, nothing gets print. how can I do that ?

Comment: okay. It's mean, `widget?.currentUser?.maxDistance != null` is true. right?

Comment: help me out pls. can I share my screen on anydesk.. stuck in it badly..

Comment: where did you get this error? ` The getter 'maxDistance' was called on null.`

Comment: I can't able to connect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232752/discussion-between-gagan-singh-and-bloodloss).